# Does a German national need a visa for Singapore or Indonesia?

Tags: visas, paperwork, singapore, indonesia, german-citizens

In 3 months, I will fly from Stuttgart, Germany to Lombok, Indonesia, with connections in Zürich, Switzerland and Singapore. I have a German passport. Do I need a visa for Singapore or Indonesia?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_German_citizens

Comment: If those are connections and you don't leave the transit area you're not technically entering Singapore, are you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you don't; you can stay in Singapore for up to 3 months without further permits and in Indonesia for 1 month.